# Quickfixj -Message 2 Rejected: Required tag missing:55

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixj

I am using Quickfixj 1.5.3 and receiving NewOrderSingle message. The message got rejected since some tags are missing but I don't want miss those messages.

My Initiator configured as
RejectInvalidMessage=N, ValidateFieldsHaveValues=N, UseDataDictionary=N.

How can I process those messages in quickfixj?

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure your DataDictionary (xml file) to reflect all of the fields that your counterparty might put in there.  Nearly all counterparties make modifications to the default FIX messages and fields, and you need to modify your DD so that the QF engine knows about those modifications.

Your counterparty should have a spec that tells you what messages and fields they use.  Review that spec and make sure your DD matches.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply. The mistake was mine, There was a jar conflict, mistakenly I kept quickfix 1.4.0 and 1.5.3 jars in my lib folder. Once I removed the 1.4.0 jar, its started behaving as expected. Applogise for my mistakes.